# $E(Y^4)$ for exponential distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was doing a question on finding the variance for an exponential distribution and happened on the term $E(Y^4)$. We have the pdf of the exponential distribution as $f(y) = \frac{1}{\beta}e^{\frac{-y}{\beta}}$ where we have $\beta = 10$. So, then we have $$E(Y^4) = \int_0^\infty y^4\frac{1}{10}e^{\frac{-y}{10}} \, dy$$ I was thinking that this looked awfully familiar to the $\Gamma$ function so I set $$E(Y^4) = 10^3\Gamma(5)$$ where $y = \frac{y}{10}$ and $$\Gamma(a) = \int_0^\infty y^{a-1}e^{-y} \, dy$$ But the answer I'm given in the solution manual is $E(Y^4) = 10^4\Gamma(5)$. Could someone please explain why they got the result they did? Why is mine wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$E(Y^4) = \int_0^\infty y^4e^{\frac{-y}{10}}\frac{1}{10}\,dy
=\int_0^\infty (10u)^4e^{-u}\,du
=10^4\int_0^\infty u^4e^{-u}\,du
=10^4\Gamma(5)
$$
where we made the substituion $u=y/10$.

Comment: on the second equality, where you substitute in $y = 10u$, what happens to $\frac{1}{10}$?

Comment: @EtherealMist  $du=(1/10)dy$

Comment: Ohhh, it's substitution method. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to find $E(Y^4)$ using mgf.

$$M_{Y}(t) = E(e^{ty}) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{ty}\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{y}{\beta}}dy = \frac{1}{\beta}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{y}{\frac{\beta}{1-\beta 
t}}}dy = \frac{1}{1-\beta t}$$

$$E(Y^4) = \frac{\partial^4 M_{Y}(t)}{\partial t^4} \bigg\vert_{t=0} = \beta^{4}\cdot1.2.3.4 = \beta^4\Gamma(5)$$

Comment: Can you explain between lines 1 and 2 how you got Beta to the 4th?

Answer (score -1):

$$
\operatorname{E}(Y^4) = \int_0^\infty y^4\frac{1}{10} e^{-y/10} \, dy = 10^4 \int_0^\infty \left( \frac y {10} \right)^4 e^{-y/10}\left( \frac{dy}{10} \right) = 10^4 \int_0^\infty u^4 e^{-u} \, du.
$$

Comment: I have trouble to understand why you post an answer (with a typo, it is $10^4$ and not $10^5$), 3 hours after the first answer (which has been accepted), and without additional information or explanations...

Comment: @fonfonx : I wanted to be explicit about writing $y/10$ wherever $u$ appears after the substitution. I think that's the simple way to do it.